# Why when I use p2.director to install Eclipse Mars.2 on Macosx there is no launcher?

Tags: eclipse, macos, installation, p2

I am installing Eclipse Mars.2 IDE on my Mac by pointing p2.director to the eclipse platform 4.5.2 repository, and it completes without error, but there is not launcher.

Here is the command I use:

> ./eclipse -nosplash -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -profileProperties org.eclipse.update.install.features=true -roaming -repository http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.5/R-4.5.2-201602121500 -installIU org.eclipse.sdk.ide -bundlepool /home/me/ecl452 -destination /home/me/ecl452 -p2.os macosx -p2.ws cocoa -p2.arch x86_64 -profile SDKProfile

There are no errors, it reports that it's installing org.eclipse.sdk.ide 4.5.2.M20160212-1500, and completes with "Operation completed in 101165 ms".  However there is no "Eclipse.app" folder in the destination, and no eclipse launcher file.  The resulting destination folder just has this:

```
-rw-r--r--  .eclipseproduct 
-rw-r--r--  artifacts.xml 
drwxr-xr-x  configuration
drwxr-xr-x  dropins
-rw-r--r--  eclipse.ini 
drwxr-xr-x  features
drwxr-xr-x  p2
drwxr-xr-x  plugins
drwxr-xr-x  readme
```

I do this kind of thing with Windows and it gives me "eclipse.exe" properly, so what am I doing wrong on the Mac?

Answer (score 1):

Adding ".app" to both the `-bundlepool` and `-destination` parameter values resulted in a launchable Eclipse instance with the executable located in the following folder:

```
/home/me/ecl452.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse
```

It seems that when the folder name ends with ".app" the p2.director recognizes that it should setup the installation as a Mac application, but with any other folder name it simply skips the application setup step without warning or error.

For completeness, here is the command that worked:

> ./eclipse -nosplash -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -profileProperties org.eclipse.update.install.features=true -roaming -repository http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.5/R-4.5.2-201602121500 -installIU org.eclipse.sdk.ide -bundlepool /home/me/ecl452.app -destination /home/me/ecl452.app -p2.os macosx -p2.ws cocoa -p2.arch x86_64 -profile SDKProfile